# Subversion adding messages without committing

Tags: svn

I am using subversion (currently 1.6). Is there a way to keep adding messages to a source code file without committing like caching the commit messages? The reason behind this is I am working on a source code in which I will be making changes most of which I have to capture during the commit. I cannot keep committing for every change. At the same time I cannot remember all those changes at the time of commit. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you keep committing for every change?

Comment: Don't you have notepad on your computer?

Comment: "Why can't you keep committing for every change?" - I may be fixing several bugs and at a time when I fixed one bug other bugs may still be there or I might have emulated something which is not relevant when committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use Git-SVN and make local commits to GIT and then push all changes to SVN in one go.

A random tutorial from Google on Git-SVN can be found [here](http://viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion).

Comment: That sounds very interesting and promising. I will definitely give it a go. Thanks Albin.

Comment: This looks like doing the job, but not in a very efficient way though (the reason is, my requirement was to cache comments and pick them up during the commit; this solution still needs multiple commits and updates svn as multiple commits as well). It is flaky. But with a little more care this nearly serves the purpose. Thanks for the tip Albin.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you create a branch and commit all your change one by one to your branch. When you have completed a "package" of work you merge your changes to trunk.

Comment: That is what I want to avoid - multiple commits. It hurts when the connection to the server is slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and use something like TortoiseSVN you could use a local pre commit hook script to add the contents of a text file to the commit message (which you will have to maintain of course). With the pre commit use should see those comments in the comment window before you actually commit... (if you dont want that - use the commit hook)

Comment: Note: Thats would be the geek-version of just copying the content of the text file to the commit message... ;-)

Comment: I agree with @FrankB. Besides I primarily use Linux.